# Cannot access SceneDelegate class variable/property

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscenedelegate

I'm trying to access a variable declared in the SceneDelegate, however, I can't access it. My code in my viewcontroller is as:

```
let sceneDelegate = self.view.window.windowScene.delegate
let variableToAccess = sceneDelegate.variableToAccess
```

I thought that would do it.. not sure what I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are trying to access is of type `UISceneDelegate`.
So to get the value you need to cast the delegate property to `SceneDelegate` like this:

```
if let sceneDelegate = self.view.window.windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
  let variableToAccess = sceneDelegate.variableToAccess
  print(variableToAccess)
}
```

Comment: Perfect casting it to SceneDelegate got me there - appreciate your time Jakub!

Comment: Its giving me AppSceneDelegate. But in my case, it is 'SceneDelegate'. So i m unable to cast AppSceneDelegate into SceneDelegate